# React Bootstrap Table KeyField with two Primary Key

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have a table with two columns that are both primary keys. How do I define the KeyField with two primary key?

prikeyarr contains [book_id, author_id].

```
<BootstrapTable keyField={props.prikeyarr} data={props.records} columns={columns} striped />
```

The code above gives me error warnings...

Therefore, in this case, I can only put one primary key as the keyField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### keyField(required) - [String]

[BootstrapTable](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/table-props.html)

I would make it in combination string, for example

```
primaryKeyString=`${book_id}_${author_id}`
```